# remove the element from list

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I will have to create a recursive function called removeList.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makeList` is a regular function, not a data constructor, so you can't pattern match on it. You need to pattern match on `Cons` and `Nil`; the fact that the list was returned by `makeList` isn't relevant.

```
removeList :: Eq a => a -> List a -> List a
removeList _ Nil = Nil
removeList x (Cons y ys) | x == y = ys -- Don't recurse if you only want to remove the *first* occurrence.
                         | otherwise = Cons y (removeList x ys)
```

You can work directly with your `List` type; there is no need to build the result as a built-in list then convert it again.

Compare to the same function implemented on built-in lists, with the type constructor `[]` and the data constructor `(:)` used in prefix position rather than infix position.

```
removeList' :: Eq a => a -> [] a -> [] a
removeList' _ [] = []
removeList' x ((:) y ys) | x == y = ys
                         | otherwise = (:) y (removeList' x ys)
```

---

Just for fun, let's generalize this code so that it can be used as the basis for both `removeFirst` and `removeAll`:

```
removeGeneric :: Eq a => (List a -> List a) -> a -> List a -> List a
removeGeneric _ _ Nil = Nil
removeGeneric f x (Cons y ys) | x == y = f y ys
                              | otherwise = Cons y (removeGeneric f x ys)

removeFirst = removeGeneric (\y ys -> ys)
removeAll = removeGeneric removeAll
```

The first argument to `removeGeneric` is the function you call on the list the first time you find a match. To remove the first occurrence, you just call the equivalent of `tail`. To remove *all* occurrences, you recurse.

Comment: If I want to remove all occurrences then what should I do?

Comment: just asking out of curiosity.But thank you for your answer.